# How to use cats typeclasses?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.instances.all._

...
  def test = Foldable[List].intercalate(List("a", "b", "c"), "-")
...
```

results into:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter instance: cats.Foldable[List]
```

Why it isn't working and how to fix it? It seems like it is just a copy from their docs:

```
scala> import cats.implicits._
scala> Foldable[List].intercalate(List("a","b","c"), "-")
res0: String = a-b-c
```

Edit 1:

Even after removing `import cats.instances.all._` as suggested it still doesn't work. Now it crashes with:

```
value intercalate is not a member of cats.Foldable[List]
```

Comment: Which version of cats are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov 0.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the instance for `Foldable[List]` twice: once through `import cats.implicits._` and once through `import cats.instances.all._`. They become ambiguous that way.

Looking at the source, you can see that `cats.instances.all` is a subset of `cats.implicits`. Simplified:

```
package cats {
  package object instances {
    object all extends AllInstances
  }

  object implicits extends syntax.AllSyntax with instances.AllInstances
}
```

Also, [it seems](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/commit/5fb96ec060fc3399afce6d412e47da3bbc646944) `Foldable.intercalate` wasn't added until cats 0.9.0.

Comment: After removing `import cats.instances.all._` it crashes with `value intercalate is not a member of cats.Foldable[List]` (I was trying various stuff I could google after it wasn't working as shown in example, that's why there are probably unnecessary imports). Also if they would be ambiguous, wouldn't have compiler said so? It looks like typeclass instances are missing ._.

Comment: It seems that cats 0.7.2 didn't have `intercalate` yet.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I googled cats and went to some obsolete fork (hence the old version) instead of the original repo :-/.